# C++ template class

Tags: c++, class, templates

```
    #ifndef ECORE_H
    #include "../database.h"
    #define ECORE_H
    Database *base_provider;  // ecore.h: error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token

    template <class S, class T>

            class ecore { // error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token


    public:

        ~ecore(void){delete base_provider;};
        ecore(void){base_provider = new Database();};
    };
#endif // ECORE_H
```

<...>

why i've any get errors in this code?

Comment: why no supply get specifics errors code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a `;` after the class declaration in `database.h`.

Comment: clang gives much better diagnostics in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps database.h contains "unbalanced" brackets or a semi-colon is missing. A classic is missing the required trailing semi-colon on class declarations.